# Using the SELF of a NSPredicate outside the format string

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using a fetchedResultsController on a CoreData store and I want to create a predicate which will give me fetchedObjects according to this concept:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%i > 0", [self countForObject:SELF]]
```

countForObject is a method which returns an integer based on the parameter anObject which I want to be the SELF.

### EDIT

It seems I should be using blocks for this. I've glued some code together but my app crashes with no feedback when I use it:

```
    [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *bindings){
        return ([self countForObject:object] > 0);
    }];
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that in your use of `self` and using an nonspecific test.

You seem to want it to refer to managed objects the predicate is testing but it will actually refer to the runtime object the code appears in (presumably a tableview controller.) Using a block does not resolve the problem because of "scope dragging" in which blocks operate within the same scope they are called from.

So, your code actually works like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%i > 0", [myTableViewController countForObject:aPresumedConstant]];
```

... and the block code has the same problem.

Your test is nonspecific because you don't test against an attribute of the managed objects. Instead you create a test that is true or false for all managed objects of the fetch's entity.

Even if your `self` reference returned a usable value it would return only one value. Suppose your `countForObject:` return -1,0,1 each on a separate run. At runtime, your predicate would resolve something like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"false", -1]; // -1<0 so %i>0 always resolves to false
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"false", 0]; // 0==0 so %i>0 always resolves to false
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"true", -1]; // 1>0 so %i>0 always resolves to true
```

In the first two cases, the fetch would return zero objects while the last would return all the objects of a the fetch entity.

You've probably seen `self` used in predicates something like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", anObject];
```

The difference here is that the `SELF` occurs within the quote marks and therefore becomes part of the message that the predicate sends to the objects being tested. The predicate essentially says, "Does you SELF key equal the SELF key of anObject?" Since every object understands its own SELF value, each object can return an individual true or false in response.

If you want each managed object to respond to test on `countForObject` you need to make `countForObject` and attribute/property of the entity/class for the managed object. Usually, you would make a transient property that would calculate a value each time it is queried and but would not persist it to the store.

You would use it something like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", anObject];
```

Comment: Very well explained, sir. I did some digging and came up with this quote: _you cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties..._ Does that mean that for my case, a transient attribute/property is not going to cut it? And regardless, will you try to help me by producing some pseudo code for making a transient attribute/property for my case?

Comment: Yeah, you can't fetch against a transient because there is nothing in the value until the object is instantiated and a predicate test doesn't trigger instantiation. The simplest solution would be make the property persistent I don't know enough about you data model or what you're trying to do to pseudocode a method for you.